# Help on function options

Tags: bash, manpage, functions

I am writing documentation for a bash function that I am writing.  It supports a colour option which can be one of `--vlt --blu --grn --ylw --orn --pur --red --wht`.  I have used the following description but am unsure whether it would be sufficiently understandable, and would like improvements this descriptive help.

```
 --COLR
   Colour Option
 
   --COLR  Brief   |  --COLR  Brief
   ----------------+----------------
   --vlt   Violet  |  --orn   Orange
   --blu   Blue    |  --pur   Purple
   --grn   Green   |  --red   Red
   --ylw   Yellow  |  --wht   White
```

Comment: I believe this would be heavily based on individual opinion, and thus off-topic here. I would suggest you do a user survey with those who should read the documentation and get their opinion instead. Cheers! 

Comment: Are there any command line programs that do this sort of option table list?

Comment: I'm sure there will be. Each program author is free to do whatever they like in their options. But since this isn't really a question about Ubuntu I agree with Artur that it isn't off topic. Personally, I would just have a `--color` option that takes values (e.g. `--color blue`) and then provide a list of acceptable values in the help message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash function documentation would be easier to understand if you replaced the ambiguous word "Brief" with the more descriptive phrase "Color name". If is a manual that is invoked from the terminal by the `man` command, you could also improve the readability by formatting the first line as bold text as is frequently done in manual pages.

```
--COLR
  Color Option

  --COLR  Color name  |  --COLR  Color name
  --------------------+--------------------
  --vlt   Violet      |  --orn   Orange
  --blu   Blue        |  --pur   Purple
  --grn   Green       |  --red   Red
  --ylw   Yellow      |  --wht   White
```